# capturar valor input text javascript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Então galera estou estudando `oop` em `javascript` to engatinhando ainda,  para isso estou tentando add no meu site elementos dinamicamente através de js

Estou querendo capturar o valor do meu campo text e quando eu clicar no botao add o elemento seja criado segue o codigo criado no jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fernandorrn/ensdt17m/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro que você cometeu foi obter o valor do `input` direto no construtor da classe. Como a classe é chamada logo no inicio da página, `this.add` vai ser sempre um valor vazio. O que você precisa fazer é obter o valor do `input` sempre que for clicado no `button`.

Veja como fica: https://jsfiddle.net/ensdt17m/1/

Comment: obrigado cara mais n tem como eu capturar o valor do input diretamente do construtor?

Comment: Tem sim, mas se você quiser um valor sempre atualizado com o que estiver no input, vai ter que obter sempre que clicar no button.

Comment: @FernandoAlcantara o que você pode fazer é passar o elemento no construtor, ficaria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/ensdt17m/2/

Comment: vlw rafael me ajudou a entender um pouco mais o conceito de orientação a objetos, n sabia que o construtor podia retornar um metodos